# LaTeX Not Rendering in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I ran a new install of Ubuntu 18.10 the other day, and installed the latest version of Anaconda3 (2019.03) and  the latest version of MikTeX. When I open up a Jupyter notebook in the base/default Conda environment, everything works as planned, except LaTeX doesn't render. In particular, the equations stay looking like $\alpha\beta\gamma$, not like their Greek counterparts.

What I've tried:

-- Restarting the notebook

-- Trying a different notebook file

-- Reinstalling Anaconda

Here's some code that I place in its own block at the top of a fresh Jupyter notebook.

```latex
$$\alpha\beta\gamma$$
$\alpha\beta\gamma$
```

Expected: Greek rendering of the above.

Actual: The text input as LaTeX code, up to and including the $$ used to indicate math mode.

Comment: Just to be sure - you did run the cell, yes? Are there any errors in the console or in the terminal where you're running the notebook server?

Comment: @Nathan I ran the cell between every step. No errors show on terminal. If you're referring to an in built Jupyter console, I'm not sure where you find that.

Comment: I mean the console for your browser. For example, pressing ctrl+shift+i opens this on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Nope, no errors in browser console.